# Arduino L led glows continuously

Tags: arduino-uno

can someone tell me why my L led on arduino uno glowing continuously I tried restarting my pc, changing USB port 
I also tried uploading an empty file and resetting the  Arduino board but nothing seems to work. Does it mean I have to buy a new one?

Comment: What happens if you upload the example blink sketch? And what, if you try to blink an LED on another pin (you need an extra LED for this)

Comment: … and a resistor

Comment: Some Arduino boards drive that LED through an op-amp. If pin 13 is set to INPUT Then the input to the op-amp will be effectively floating. That can cause the LED to glow since it lacks further instruction on what to do.

Comment: I ran a blink code using pin 13 and an LED both L and LED is now blinking. But if I ran an empty code the L led is on continuously  also if I connect an LED with the empty code uploaded both the L Led and external LED goes out

Comment: Does L LED glowing continuously mean something? bcuz the programs that I run seem to do the work

Answer (score 1):

Don't let that pin float undefined: If undefined (INPUT), pull it to GND to have the led OFF.

If ever possible, try to use the LED_BUILTIN pin as an OUTPUT pin.

And signal some information there. On an UNO (or other 328-based Arduino), this hint might collide with the SPI_SCK pin, which is D13 (PB5 on an atmega328). But as an SPI Master, this pin is at least OUTPUT (and thus will signal SPI activity).